# How to save a formatted string?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if its possible to save a formatted string in python in any way?

For example, could I create an arbitrary string like this:

```
s = f"This is my string. This is a {variable}"
```

and then save it in a csv or an SQL database for later use given that variable would always be set before loading?

I have already tried this with a CSV document and in MySQL without much luck so I concluded that this wasn't possible. Google hasn't given much of a result either.

My specific problem is that I have a large file containing hundreds of symptoms. Each symptom is a class and inherits a parent class which contains 7 base questions regarding the symptom. I would like to load a formatted string in the parent class for the sublass to load(as it inherits the parent class). An example would be something along these lines:

In Parent class:

```
self.question = f"Do you have a {self.symptom}?"
```

In Headache class:

```
self.symptom = "headache"
```

would be parsed to the string: "Do you have a headache?" etc.

I would really like to load the questions from a database for maintainance purposes since maintaining a large .py file with large number of classes, each with a question in a string format would end up as a total nightmare.

Thanks!

Edit: spelling

Comment: Can you clarify just a bit what you mean? So in the saved csv there would be formatted text, and depending on how that csv is called the `self.question` would be initiated from the csv with the correct `self.symptom`?

Comment: It might help to see the "head" of your symptom file as well. Just the first 5 lines or so, because I think there is a simple solution to this, but I don't exactly understand your goal.

Comment: In the CSV document would be a formatted string, e.g. f"Do you have a {self.symptom}". In the class instance, on init, self.symptom is set to a symptom, f.x. "headache" and I would like to be able to load the string from the CSV document and have it be formatted to "Do you have a headache"

Comment: I would look into pickling, this way you can save the `object` itself and pick it up again through unpickling. A lot safer than using `exec` and you have the whole object available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick idea, but I wouldn't recommend it:
Storing it into a string, to execute it:

```
self.generatequestion = 'question1=f"Do you have a {self.symptom}?"'
```

in Headache:

```
self.symptom = "headache"
```

And then

```
exec(self.generatequestion1)
print(question1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I've always been a bit afraid of using exec / eval because of debugging problems. That said, I don't have a lot of experience using them. Perhaps this is a good use case?

Comment: I would use `eval` here and assign question1 to that like `question1 = eval(self.generatequestion1)`, much much safer.

Comment: The downside of this is that this also becomes a maintainance nightmare when using large dictionaries as I am using. Each dictionary has ~ around 10 attributes, one of which are choices which is a list of dictionaries. So this becomes a lot to maintain and hard to debug if I would construct a .py file containing 200-300 classes, each containing 7 base questions, each containing 10 attributes, each containing 1-5 choices and everything is saved as a parsable string :/ Maybe I could create a seperate class for only loading these strings from file which would help with getting more oversight